# Отвалился eth0 - OpenWRT и HummingBoard

Tags: linux, debian, сеть, openwrt

Здравствуйте. На столе лежит `HummingBoard  i.MX6 Solo`. Решил установить на него `OpenWRT`, оставил `u-boot` и `kernel` от прошлой `ОС Cubox-i`. Система запустилась. Одна проблема, она не видит сетевую карту. Прошу специалистов помочь решить эту проблему.

Comment: программа linux была собрана монолитно или с модулями? если с модулями, вы не забыли их скопировать?

Comment: все было собрано с модулями. я скопировал весь rootfs

Comment: *я скопировал весь rootfs* — так что же у вас там тогда от *openwrt*?

Comment: Я скомпилировал cubox-i; в нем образ с u-boot, dps, kernel и debian. Далее я создал образ openwrt и скопировал только операционную систему openwrt на SD карточку, заменяя debian.

Comment: модули сохранили? они в состоянии загружаться? что выдаёт `lsmod`? linux скомпилирована с псевдо-фс `/sys`? что выдаёт `ls -l /sys/class/net/*/`? что выдаёт `lspci`? добавьте, пожалуйста, всю запрошенную информацию в вопрос.

Comment: `lsmod`ничего не выдает, `ls -l /sys/class/net/*/` выдает папки `../eth0/` и `.../lo/`, `lspci` выдает `00:00.0 PCI bridge: Device 16c3:abcd (rev 01)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26915/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-insider).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы пишете, что «оставили загрузчик и программу *linux*» от какой-то «прошлой» операционной системы.

если программа *linux* в этой «прошлой» системе была скомпилирована с использованием модулей, то скопировать надо было **также и** скомпилированные модули.